# How to display menu items based on sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, user-permissions, user-roles, session-storage

I'm kind of lost in which is the best way to proceed. After fetching the user data from an API, I store the user data in the sessionStorage. How can I display menu items based on roles (ie- Admin, Representative, Guest).

I have a basic Bootstrap Sidebar that looks like below.

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
 <li><a>Home</a>
   <ul class="sidebar-dropdown">
     <li>Default</li>
     <li>Reports</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a>Contact</a>
    <ul class="sidebar-dropdown">
      <li>Admin Contact</li>
      <li>Contact 1</li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Should I add classes to menu items based on roles to my menu items and with a JavaScript function that runs on load display or hide menu items??

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/edkLpcbw/7/)

Comment: It should be other way around. You should populate list `ul` by available links after you receive data. Hiding is not enough. You really want to remove them because user doesn't have access to them at all.

Comment: so something like ```const list = routes.map( route => `<li><link href=${route.link}>${route.title}</link></li>);```and then inject it to your `ul`. `ULelement.innerHTML = list.join("")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My initial thinking was an object like this (please see updated fiddle): [link](https://jsfiddle.net/q70th8n1/3/)  but I can't get it to work with the example you provided. How else should I be structuring my links??

Comment: you have a couple of issues there, see my answer for working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is dynamically render a list based on data. Receiving data from session storage is not an issue because it can be done by

```js
JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data'));
```

your issue is to render them. Try to use hardcoded data first to see if you are able to render what you want and then just plug in data from the storage. For an example
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-fast-my3ud?file=/src/index.js

```js
const routes = [
  {
    href: "/home",
    title: "Home",
    children: [
      {
        href: "/home/defaults",
        title: "Defaults"
      },
      {
        href: "/home/reports",
        title: "Reports"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    href: "/contact",
    title: "Contact",
    children: [
      {
        href: "/contact/admin-contact",
        title: "Admin Contanct"
      },
      {
        href: "/contact/contact-1",
        title: "Contact 1"
      }
    ]
  }
];

function renderSingleRoute(route) {
  const children = route.children ? renderRoutes(route.children) : "";
  return `
    <li>
      <a href="${route.href}">${route.title}</a>
      ${children}
    </li>
  `;
}

function renderRoutes(routes) {
  return `
    <ul>
      ${routes.map((route) => renderRoute(route)).join("")}
    </ul>
  `;
}

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = renderRoutes(routes);
```

So the idea here is to build your routes however you want and then pass it to render function

Comment: Thanks for you working example, I got it to work. Basically the returned user data should include the permission routes object so I can build my links. Why is there a trailing comma after `li` elements? [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/oL4d1haj/2/)

Comment: its because `routes.map((route) => renderRoute(route))` will render to array separated with commas. just join them as `routes.map((route) => renderRoute(route)).join("")`. I updated the example

Comment: Pleas accept the answer if it answered your question. Thank you.